# GCP cloudbuild.yaml creates "workspace/tests" but need "workspace/my_app/tests"

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Noob at working with Cloud Build. Trying to run tests but it's missing the top project folder in the path. I can't figure out how in the build steps to fix this. Project structure is:

```
gcp_cicd_workflow
  |-- src
     | my_module.py
  |-- tests
     | test_my_module.py
```

At the point where cloud build tries to run the tests is errors out:

```
imported module 'test_my_module' has this __file__ attribute:
/workspace/gcp-cicd-workflow/tests/test_my_module.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
/workspace/tests/test_my_module.py
```

This makes perfect sense to me since by default, Cloud Build uses a directory named /workspace as a working directory. What I somehow need to do is figure out how to create the path `workspace/gcp-cicd-workflow` so build can find my tests.

Here's my cloudbuild.yaml file in its entirety (up to the point it errors out:

```
steps:

  # Step 0
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['clone', '--recurse-submodules', 'https://github.com/GDBSD/gcp-cicd-workflow']

  # Step 1
  # Variable $COMMIT_SHA provided by the Cloud Build so we test the correct commit.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: [ 'checkout', '$COMMIT_SHA']
  dir: 'gcp-cicd-workflow'

  # Step 2
  # Cloud Build automatically substitutes $PROJECT_ID for your Project ID
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/python-cloudbuild'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c', 'python3 -m venv /workspace/venv']

  # Step 3
  # Installs any dependencies listed in the project's requirements.txt.
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/python-cloudbuild'
  entrypoint: 'venv/bin/pip'
  args: ['install', '-V', '-r', 'requirements.txt']

  # Step 4
  # Runs pytest from the virtual environment (with all requirements)
  # using the verbose flag so you can see each individual test.
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/python-cloudbuild'
  entrypoint: 'venv/bin/python'
  args: ['-m', 'pytest', '-v']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a custom builder and I don't know how is work. It maybe work with absolute path and it should be the issue.

Anyway, a simple way to solve your issue is to clone your repository into the current directory, I mean in `/workspace/` like this

```
# Step 0, simply add a . as final arg
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['clone', '--recurse-submodules', 'https://github.com/GDBSD/gcp-cicd-workflow', '.']
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of just doing everything from the command line but wanted to make use of the builder tools. All my custom builder does is use a one-line docker to add Python 3.

Comment: If you use simply Python and PIP without any customization in your pipeline, you can directly use the official images! No custom builder require for this!

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. That is my intuition too at this point. Key objective is CI/CD, and I need to run the tests in Builder or in some fashion before I deploy. Probably can get that all done in any number of ways. Was working with this tutorial: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/python-cicd-with-cloudbuilder